# Firebase Database has insecure rules even though the rules are necessary

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This was asked quite a lot but I still don't know what I can do to silence the warning I am getting every week from Firebase ...

> Your Cloud-Firestore database has insecure rules

As you can guess my rules are **all can read & write**.

My problem is that I actually need that. Inside the SignUp process I need to access all the users emails and usernames to check if the currently selected is available or not. And after the User has signed up he is able to search for other users and create/delete/change his own files.

I don't quite get how I can get rid of the security issue. Where is the threat ?

Comment: If your users can create/delete/update only his own files then your rules wouldn't be read/write true.

Comment: oh I that makes sense, so in my case I would need  a *all read*  and *write own files* right? How is that done ? My Structure is basically like this: **useres**/(userID)/**documents**

Comment: You just describe your own rules, write only for the user where uid is equal to user id, and the read part you don't need it, make a Function to ask safely about user availability, creating another node where you have all the user is also suitable but expose information

Comment: @cutiko do you know the syntax for my case? users also have several more subcollections so the answer below is not working

Comment: btw, I am saving the every user after he signs up (random generated doc-name) and every user has a field "uid"  with his actual firebase-userID

Comment: I would suggest the approach is wrong. Firebase Authentication doesn't allow duplicate email addresses (using email/pw auth) so if it already exists, the create user function will return an error. Additionally there's a function that can be used to check for an account `Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email)` and can be found in the auth documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth#differentiating_emailpassword_from_email_link). Please don't allow everyone to read your Firebase as it's a security issue and an instant email list for the baddies.

Comment: @Jay I am using that `method` to check but I also need to check the username before the user is created and for that I need to read, and users have access to other users data so I need that as well

Comment: Why? Authentication creates the account and authenticates the user so then the app can query to see if the user name is available. If not, ping the user for a different user name. If the user cancels, delete the account (which can be done since it's authenticated). I am suggesting options here as leaving user data exposed to anyone is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @Jay thats a good point. I will work on that! thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

As I said in then comments if your users can create/delete/update only his own files then your rules wouldn't be read/write true. As i understand you need to have all users to be able to read but you want them to write only to their own documents. 
On way to do it is by putting the document id the same as the user id and then use the below rules to check if it is valid.

```
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow read: true;
    }
```

Comment: I actually want everyone to read because I need to read the Database even before the user is created. btw, your answer says write twice, maybe edit that and I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Yeah, i miss typed :P

Comment: ye i know :D so does your answer work for users only or can someone who is not a user read as well ?

Comment: Btw, you can even check based on specific value inside a document. Eg if you save the user id inside a value of document x. Then you can create a rule that says if the user id field inside of the x matches the authentication user id.

Comment: The write will work only for authenticated users, the read for all. If someone doesn't want to sign in you can authenticate him anonymously.

Comment: ok I tried to implement that but it is not working. It's because of the Databse-Ref. I have several SubCollections. Can I simply use `match /{document=**}`  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211292/discussion-between-chris-and-chris-papantonis).

Answer (score 0):

So, finally got it right. With this solution everyone can *read* and user can only *write* their own stuff.

Here is my code:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /users/{userId} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow read;
      match /{allSubcollections=**} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow read;
      }
    }
  }
}
```